# Ruby NoMethodError on every method in a random class in a single Passenger process

Tags: ruby, passenger, nomethoderror

On two separate occasions, we have seen a single Passenger process having NoMethodError issue with a single class. It would throw NoMethodError on any method in a single class the code tries to access. It was as if the class was empty. The same code is ran on 10+ other hosts and also many other Passenger processes on the same host, but none of them would experience this issue. The issue would go away if the problematic process gets killed and restarted.

We initially suspected something overloaded the class at runtime. However, when this issue happened for the second time, the issue occurred on a different class. Our suspicion is on Ruby interpreter or Passenger, but we do not have any lead on the root cause.

Ruby version: 1.9.3
Rails version: 2.3.18

Redacted stack trace from the 2nd occurrence. In this case, it was a module, but the first occurrence was on an ActiveRecord class:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `exponential_bounded' for Retry:Module):

app/controllers/pack_controller.rb:242:in `pack'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:321:in `save_html'
lib/memory_usage_filter.rb:58:in `call'
lib/memory_usage_filter.rb:58:in `filter'
lib/query_log_filter.rb:34:in `call'
lib/query_log_filter.rb:34:in `block in filter'
.../ruby1.9/site_ruby/1.9.1/amazon/querylog.rb:646:in `time'
lib/query_log_filter.rb:26:in `filter'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
.../lib/phusion_passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in   `process_request'
.../lib/phusion_passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:513:in  `accept_and_process_next_request'
.../lib/phusion_passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in   `main_loop'
.../lib/phusion_passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:206:in   `start_request_handler'
.../lib/phusion_passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:171:in   `block in handle_spawn_application'
.../lib/phusion_passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
.../lib/phusion_passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:166:in `handle_spawn_application'
.../lib/phusion_passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:358:in `server_main_loop'
.../lib/phusion_passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:207:in `start_synchronously'
.../lib/phusion_passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:181:in `start'
.../lib/phusion_passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:129:in `start'
.../lib/phusion_passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
.../lib/phusion_passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
.../lib/phusion_passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
.../lib/phusion_passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
.../lib/phusion_passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
.../lib/phusion_passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
.../lib/phusion_passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
.../lib/phusion_passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
.../lib/phusion_passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:358:in `server_main_loop'
.../lib/phusion_passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:207:in `start_synchronously'
.../lib/phusion_passenger/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Does this happen when the server (re)starts or randomly when the server is up and running for some time?

Comment: Randomly. That being said, our passenger processes get killed and restarted after certain time if not being used. So it could be right after the passenger process restarts.